# Почему не работает background в CardView

Tags: android, kotlin, cardview

Почему не работает что не так?
back_card.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <corners
        android:radius="24dp"/>
    <stroke
        android:width="5dp"
        android:color="#D5D6D7" />
    <solid android:color="@color/black"/>
    <size
        android:height="390dp"
        android:width="320dp"/>
</shape>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Выглядит так, что атрибут `background` не поддерживается для `CardView`, но фон для карточки можно выставить с помощью кода:

```kotlin
cardView.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.back_card)
```

Comment: Спасибо большое, я как раз искал как его через код попробовать. Работает, но вот почему в разметке выставить можно а по факту не работает. И все время так, надоели эти недоработки спс еще раз большое, вы спасли мой день.