# Как через код изменить background у cardView?

Tags: android, kotlin

В таком виде код не компилируется:

```java
binding.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(R.colors.color_1);
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1306900/177345

Answer (score 2):

Данный метод принимает цвет, а не ресурс. Надо так:

```java
binding.cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(
    ContextCompat.getColor(getContext(), R.colors.color_1));
```

Answer (score 1):

Внимательно смотрите сигнатуры методов, которые вызываете. Приведенный вами метод `setCardBackgroundColor` принимает на вход `@ColorInt`. А то, что вы пытаетесь передать — это айди ресурса, `@ColorRes` (или `@DrawableRes` в более широком смысле).

Вам нужно преобразовать айди ресурса в цвет (как уже ответил @Yura):

```java
@ColorInt int color = ContextCompat.getColor(this, R.color.black);
cardView.setCardBackgroundColor(color)
```

Либо просто воспользоваться другим методом, `setBackgroundResource`, у которого на входе `int` с аннотацией `@DrawableRes`. В качестве `@DrawableRes` можно передавать `@ColorRes`:

```java
@ColorRes int colorRes = R.color.black;
cardView.setBackgroundResource(colorRes);
```

[Вот тут](https://developer.android.com/studio/write/annotations#res-annotations) можно посмотреть, какие еще бывают аннотации.